# If file name contains specific text then pull information from filename (excel vba)

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have a database of about 140,000 test files. I am looking to loop through each folder and pull information from the file name of text and excel files so as to organize the data a little better.

I have found ways to pick a folder path and import information about each file using the code below. This works great except I would like to only pull information from excel and text files and I would also like to pull additional text information from the filename as well. For example I might have a file named:

"444555_CAT1010EL_650-700-800C-2hr laging NOT CH4.txt"

And I would want to print:

- the 6 numbers at the beginning of the name (they could be anything) in this example "444555" in one column
- print the 3 letters (they could be anything) before "1010EL" in another column. In this example "CAT"
- "CH4" in the final column OR even have a column for "CH4" and if the filename contains "CH4" put an X in that column
- have a column for "laging" and if the filename contains "laging" anywhere put an X in that column

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Sub Compile3()
  Dim oShell As Object
  Dim oFile As Object
  Dim oFldr As Object
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim iCol As Integer
  Dim vArray As Variant
  vArray = Array(10, 0, 1, 156, 2, 4, 144, 146, 183, 185)

  '0=Name, 31=Dimensions, 1=Size, 163=Vertical Resolution

  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'-------------------ROW INFO INPUT OPTIONS-----------------
'' 1)
'  lRow = 1
' 2) find first empty row in database for bottletracker
'
  Dim iRow As Long
  iRow = Cells.find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
   lRow = iRow
'------------------------------------------------------------

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .title = "Select the Folder..."
    If .Show Then
      Set oFldr = oShell.Namespace(.SelectedItems(1))
      With oFldr
      'Column header information
        For iCol = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
          Cells(lRow, iCol + 4) = .getdetailsof(.items, vArray(iCol))
        Next iCol

        For Each oFile In .items
          lRow = lRow + 1
          For iCol = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            Cells(lRow, iCol + 4) = .getdetailsof(oFile, vArray(iCol))
          Next iCol
        Next oFile
      End With
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify where in your code the filename is being retrieved.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code - the tags include helpful text to provide guidance when and when not to use them.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I use the FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) function that is built in which allows me to select any folder path for my sub.

Then using "With" I pull the information I want (using the .getdetailsof) for each file in that folder path. This function works great for pulling file size, name, etc.

I'm hoping to pull characters from the actual file names which I have imported using .getdetailsof

Comment: Then all the work you want to add would go in place of `Cells(lRow, iCol + 4) = .getdetailsof(oFile, vArray(iCol))`? If so, I think you should delete all the other code, and just focus on what you want to do instead of that line.

Comment: @bluemonkMN I was hoping that someone would have experience with manipulating file information using the 'Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)'. There are really only 2 parts to the above code (creating the headers and pulling the info for each file). I guess I'm not sure what you would like me to take out.

Comment: Will the numbers you want at the beginning **always** be 6 characters or will they **always** be all the characters before the first underscore, similarly will `CAT` always be directly before `101EL` or will they **always** be 8th - 10th characters, or **always** the three characters after the first underscore.  I ask because so often we're given examples as it applies to the current text, but it doesn't work on the next text string.

Comment: @bluemonkmn I could just take all the code out and ask for help pulling information from a file name. All the information needed to solve that simplified problem is in the question description. If you have any insight (ignoring my code) that would be much appreciated. I can then figure out how to integrate your solution with the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`

Comment: Not a comment on your asked for info, but you're setting `iRow` twice without doing anything between.  That line of code will also fail if the activesheet is empty.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook **assuming** I can find a solution that will filter the files pulled so that I only get **txt or excel files** the #'s at the beginning will **always** be 6 characters. As for everything else the placement varies. I just want to know if `CAT` and `CH4` and `laging` are in the filename and if so mark an X in the CAT, CH4, and laging columns respectively. Great questions

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook you are also right about the `iRow` thing. I will take out the duplicate. And the active sheet should never be empty but if you have a fix for that error that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use this code.  There's three separate procedures at the end that find the last cell on the sheet, return the folder and return all files within the folder.

The main code then looks at each file name and pulls the required information from it.
Note, this code:  `InStr(sFileName, "CAT") <> 0` will return TRUE/FALSE depending if the text "CAT" is within the file name.  `InStr(sFileName, "CAT")` returns the position of "CAT" within the text, and `<>0` turns that into a boolean depending on if it's different from 0.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim cFiles As Collection
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim rLastCell As Range

    sFolder = GetFolder("S:\DB_Development_DBC\") & Application.PathSeparator

    Set cFiles = New Collection
    EnumerateFiles sFolder, "*.xls*", cFiles
    EnumerateFiles sFolder, "*.txt", cFiles

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each vFile In cFiles
             Set rLastCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")).Offset(1) 'Find last row
             sFileName = Mid(vFile, InStrRev(vFile, Application.PathSeparator) + 1) 'Get just file name from path.
             .Cells(rLastCell.Row, 1) = Left(sFileName, 6) 'First 6 characters.
             .Cells(rLastCell.Row, 2) = Mid(sFileName, InStr(sFileName, "1010EL") - 3, 3) '3 characters before 1010EL.
             .Cells(rLastCell.Row, 3) = InStr(sFileName, "CH4") <> 0 'Contains CH4.
             .Cells(rLastCell.Row, 4) = InStr(sFileName, "laging") <> 0 'Contains laging.
        Next vFile
    End With

End Sub

Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef cCollection As Collection)

    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        cCollection.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub

Function GetFolder(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = vItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Else
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

**Edit:**
I've updated the code to include the other requirements and moved finding the last cell to within the loop so it actually works.

Note:
`Mid(sFileName, InStr(sFileName, "1010EL") - 3, 3)` - this code will throw an error if the text doesn't contain *1010EL*.  Add a check that `InStr(sFileName, "1010EL") <> 0` before letting that line execute.

Comment: thank you for putting time into this. I ran the code as you've provided it and the code only pulls  the 6 digits and the TRUE/FALSE for "CAT" for 1 file of 50 in the folder I selected. Is there something I need to alter?

Comment: Also I was not sure what the `("S:\DB_Development_DBC\")` in `GetFolder("S:\DB_Development_DBC\") & Application.PathSeparator` was for. Do I need to alter that?

Comment: Oops, sorry. That's the file path I was using to test. It's the default path that the select folder starts at. You can change it to something more suitable or just use GetFolder()

Comment: Application.PathSeparator is just a \.

Comment: I've just realised I haven't given all the code for extracting the text. You can use INSTR to find 1010EL in the text and MID to extract the three lets before it. On my phone at the moment so can't give any tested code.

Comment: Okay cool. I'll try to figure it out and if you have time once you're back at your console and you want to fix it I'll check back later. Thanks for your help so far